# Is there a way to follow a binding in code?

Tags: wpf, data-binding

If i have a Binding which has a property path and the data source can i execute it in code, to find the value?

The path that i am trying to follow can be quite complicated, including collection lookup and multiple levels.

there is a hack :

create a content control
use BindingOperations.SetBinding()

then retrieve the content

is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid using a `ContentControl`, and write your own very simple class that derives directly from `DependencyObject`, and provides a single `DependencyProperty`, which you can then target with the binding. Aside from that, no, there isn't any better way - binding machinery in WPF is very much tied into the concept of dependency properties, and a binding cannot really be a "free-standing expression" that is just evaluated.

Comment: thought so, but it never hurts to ask. thanks for the more efficient solution, ill derive straight from DP