# Is there a way to refer to a binding in the code behind

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, data-binding

I'm using the Actipro ribbon in my application and making use of the way that one can integrate a document title with the main ribbon title when a standard mdi host is being used (the docking is also Actipro docking).  Now whilst I'm using a specific vendor's controls I think / hope that my question is a little more generic.

Currently the Xaml that is providing this functionality is marked up like this.

```
<ribbon:RibbonWindow.DocumentName>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ConditionalConverter}">
        <Binding ElementName="window" Path="IsMDIChildMaximized" />
        <Binding ElementName="standardMdiHost" Path="PrimaryWindow.Title" />
        <Binding Source="{x:Null}" />
    </MultiBinding>
</ribbon:RibbonWindow.DocumentName>
```

The ribbon itself is named so in the code behind I can write something along the lines of;

```
 MainRibbonWindow.DocumentName
```

However I can't get as far as the MultiBinding.  Very specifically I would like to find a way to dynamically set ElementName on the second line of the binding in the xaml

```
<Binding ElementName="standardMdiHost" Path="PrimaryWindow.Title" />
```

because I know that the actual standardmdihost that is being refered to will change (everything else will remain the same).

The whole area of binding in wpf is still proving to be a very sharp learning curve, so I'd welcome any suggestions as to how I might go about achieving the desired result, or even if it's possible to do so in the first place.

I have come across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911367/is-there-a-way-to-follow-a-binding-in-code) post, but I'm not sure if it really is the answer and even if it is how I would set about implementing it in this situation.

Many thanks

EDIT

Realised that I could probably do this in code by setting bindings along this sort of line:

```
 Dim binding As New MultiBinding() With {.Converter = New BooleanAndConverter()}
    binding.Bindings.Add(New Binding("AreWindowsMaximized") With {.Source = host})
    binding.Bindings.Add(New Binding("HasItems") With {.Source = host})
    Me.SetBinding(IsMDIChildMaximizedProperty, binding)
```

However preliminary attempts

```
 Dim binding2 As New MultiBinding() With {.Converter = New ConditionalConverter()}
    binding2.Bindings.Add(New Binding("Binding1") with {.ElementName = "MainRibbonWindow", .Path = IsMDIChildMaximized}
```

are not going quite as expected.  If anyone could hazard a guess at what might work I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have much more luck by data binding the `DocumentName` property to a property in your view model. That way, you are free to generate the value in code... perhaps something like this:

In XAML:

```
<ribbon:RibbonWindow DocumentName="{Binding DocumentName, Mode=OneWay}" ... />
```

In code:

```
public string DocumentName
{
    get { return string.Format("{0}{1}", Value1, Value2); }
}

private string Value1
{
    get { return value1; }
    set { value1 = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("DocumentName");
}

private string Value2
{
    get { return value2; }
    set { value2 = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("DocumentName");
}
```

Then you just need to set `Value1` and `Value2` to whatever values you need and they will update the `DocumentName` using the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface (or more accurately, the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface will notify the UI of a change in the `DocumentName` property and then retrieve the latest value).

Comment: Many thanks for your suggestion. In the end (with I have to admit some great support from the folks at Actipro we came up with the code that I have added in an answer just below this

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone should stumble across this and have a similar issue.  My original mistake was in failing to properly understand how the bindings syntax worked and that all the clues needed to do this successfully were already in the xaml that I was looking to remove and replace wit code.

The end result (which does work) turned out to be;

```
 Dim binding2 As New MultiBinding() With {.Converter = New ConditionalConverter()}
    binding2.Bindings.Add(New Binding("IsMDIChildMaximized") With {.Source = MainRibbonWindow})
    binding2.Bindings.Add(New Binding("PrimaryWindow.Title") With {.Source = host})
    SetBinding(DocumentNameProperty, binding2)
```

This was a very specific issue involving the Actipro ribbon and docking ommands and the two sources (MainRibbonWindow and host) are the main window whose title we are trying to integrate with that of the document window, and the standardMdiHost itself.

I'd just like to take this opportunity to express my thanks both to those of you who read this question and posted suggestions and to Actipro themselves who pointed out the error of my ways and provided the final correct code that worked.